# Synchronously checking if a child process failed to spawn in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I spawn a child process. After I spawn it, I write to the outgoing stream, so I want to synchronously detect if it failed to spawn before doing that (otherwise I get a `write EPIPE` error).

```
let proc = cp.spawn("path/file.exe");
proc.on("error", (err) => { throw err; });
proc.stdin.write(...);
```

Now if I put the `write` on a `setTimeout(() => { proc.stdin.write(...); }, 0)`, the `error` handler will get hit first, and we'll crash before doing the `write`, but that's a little ugly.

What I have found is that after `cp.spawn` returns, we can check the `proc.pid` property, and if it's a number, we know that the process spawned. If we give it the path of a nonexistent executable, `proc.pid` is `undefined`, so it seems that we can synchronously check if the process failed to spawn, and we don't need to rely on the asynchronous `error` callback (though the callback catches other errors).

Node's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) has a section on checking for a failed spawn, but it suggests the asynchronous method:

```
const subprocess = spawn('bad_command');

subprocess.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Failed to start subprocess.');
});
```

Nowhere does it mention that checking for an `undefined` `proc.pid` is a suitable synchronous alternative for checking for a failed spawn, which me leads to wonder if this a robust and recommended way of doing it. Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: spawning a sub process is not a synchronous operation.  So, you can't check if it succeeded synchronously.

Comment: @jfriend00 So you're saying that even if I get a numeric pid back, it might fail farther along the spawning process and we'll enter the `error` handler? In that case, I take it that I'm forced to not do the `write` synchronously. However, I don't see any `success` type of event. So must I do the `setTimeout(()=>{}, 0)` thing, or is there a better way? I guess I could try to ping the process by sending it a message...

Comment: You'd have to study the node.js source code on multi platforms to try to figure out if you can always use the existence of the pid as an indicator of success or failure. It seems clear that if the pid is not there, then it did fail. But, the reverse is not necessarily true because it could perhaps fail later in the steps where a pid was created, but still failed after that and then triggered the `error` event.  It seems like if `proc.stdin` exists, you should be able to write to it without error.  It is a stream so you may have to pay attention to flow control if you're writing larger amounts.

Comment: just wondering .. did you try `sapwnSync()` ?

Comment: @Taki `spawnSync` will only return once the process has exited, which isn't what I want.

Comment: @pushkin thanks a bunch for posting your question and answer here. I can't believe that so far seemingly so few people wanted to build solid child process management in NodeJS where indeed we need to have a _reliable_ way to catch real-world system call errors like ENOENT or EACCES, synchronously, before proceeding in application code. It's not about finding a magic philosophical definition for "when did a child process come to life successfully?", but about having a documented, reliable way to handle common errors thrown by the underlying system calls for starting the child process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chatted with the folks at Node. Quoting from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1191#issuecomment-377804190).

> Is there anyway to detect if a process has successfully spawned?

Sadly, no, not in the general case.

> I have no guarantee that the process successfully spawned until I start actually writing to its streams and get errors.

Yup, that’s correct. libuv does a best-effort thing here, but it’s impossible to get a guaranteed result without resorting to e.g. polling techniques that look up the process pid and what that process is currently doing.

> I have found that I can check `proc.pid` right after `spawn`ing, and if I pass in a faulty path, it's `undefined`. If I pass in the correct path, it's set to a number, which seems promising. However, someone on SO said that the spawning might still fail after the OS gives back a pid.

Part of the problem here is that there is no clear line for determining what a “failed” spawn attempt means – at what point do you consider a process spawned successfully? There can be errors at any point during process setup.

> What exactly is guaranteed after the `spawn` function returns?

On Unix, that the [`execve()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call was entered in the child process, and it succeeded in loading the relevant parts of the target executable into memory.

On Windows, a similar thing goes for [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Either way, there are still plenty of reasons why starting a process might fail – missing DLLs/shared libraries, memory exhaustion while running setup code, etc.

> At what point in the spawning process are we?

If the `spawn()` call succeeds, all you know that it’s up to the OS and the spawned process. No code from Node.js/libuv will be executed anymore inside the child.

> And can I rely on this `proc.pid === undefined` technique?

For checking whether the executable could be found, yes, that’s reliable.

> If not, how can I at least asynchronously know if the process successfully spawned?

The only thing that comes to my mind would be polling the OS’s way of providing information about the process tree in general.

> Why is there no `success` callback?

When, and most importantly, from where would that callback be called? `spawn()` finishing means that the OS and the target executable’s code are in charge now, so Node.js can’t make the process do something like saying “I’m good to go”.

---

Another user recommends:

> One thing you could do, is in the child process, write to stdout "spawned successfully", read from stdout in the parent process, and then wait for that message.

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');
let stdout = '';

k.on('data', function(d){
  stdout+= String(d);
 if(stdout.match(/spawned successfully/)){
     // do your thing
  }
});
```